# Understanding how Django's cache framework works and dealing with cached pages for different user roles

Tags: python, django, caching, django-1.8

I am having an issue where pages are not being displayed correctly for a certain user role and I am sure the problem is caching. The page is a partial view of a sports schedule which is loaded with AJAX:

```
url(pattern, cache_page(CACHE_TIMEOUT)(last_modified(season_modified(dont_vary_on("Cookie")(ScheduleView.as_view()))), name='schedule_partial')
```

Note that `season_modified` is a function that retuns the last time the season/schedule was modified. It is used to refresh the cache.

Here is the problem:

When a user browses the schedule page view as an anonymous or non-authorized user, the schedule with the non-authorized bits will be loaded and cached. Then if they log it or switch accounts as a referee, the page should load with several referee-related elements, mainly score inputs so they can keep match scores. However, it seems that the non-authorized cached version of the page is loaded, so they cannot interact with the schedule as they should. The opposite scenario also happens: if a referee views the page and it is cached, then logs out, they will see the authorized page as anonoymous user, when they shouldn't.

However, if I log in with my staff account, or if a schedule admin logs in, the admin/staff version of the page is loaded, which is what we want.

My understanding of how this cache framework works is that once the route is accessed by *anyone*, the page is generated and cached. From then on, until the cache expires, that cached page is going to be served to *everybody*. Is that how it works?

That would explain why referees are seeing the wrong page, but... shouldn't admins have the same problem too then? Please help me understand how this works.

And the second point of this question is solving the main issue: how can I load the correct version of the page when a referee user opens it up?

Comment: When you login with your staff account, are you making a GET request to the same URLs?

Comment: Your understanding of how the cache works is correct. But what does `dont_vary_on("Cookie")` do? Show us the code.

Comment: Also since this is accessed via Ajax, what bit of information in the HTTP request indicates that their login status has changed? Is a session cookie sent? Or is there an extra auth header? In which case you should "vary_on" that specific header.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers) for more information on how to influence the caching based on the headers.

Comment: @dirkgroten I am thinking I could set up a "last logged in role" cookie (staff, admin, referee, anonymous), send it with the request, and expire the cached or not based on that? Does that sound good?

Comment: @dirkgroten I am not sure about the `dont_vary_on("Cookie")` bit. I didn't write that part. It does seem to be a Django decorator, here's what the documentation says: "Decorator that changes response to mark that certain HTTP headers must not be included in the Vary header". Not sure what that's for or what it does.

Comment: No, it's not part of Django, where do you see that documentation? There's `vary_on_headers` and `vary_on_cookie`. But I would do this with an extra header, because cookie doesn't discriminate which cookie and you could have a session also for anonymous users.

Comment: If you're caching the view, there's no reason to also cache the rendered template. Remove the {% cache %} directive.

Comment: @dirkgroten the templated cached by the `cache` tag is a more extense, wrapping template. The view the whole post is about is merely loaded with ajax as a partial within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of how the caching mechanism works is correct. By default if anyone accesses a URL, it will be cached for everyone else.

Since you're not showing the code for `dont_vary_on` decorator, which isn't a standard Django decorator, we can't tell you why it seems to work for staff (if you're sure they are accessing the same URL).

But basically you need to vary the cache key depending on the HTTP request headers, so that if those headers change, the page is re-rendered. Read about [Vary headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers). The Django cache middleware honours these headers.

Comment: I am trying to implement what you suggested but something is not going well. I am trying to add a header to the AJAX request like this: `$.ajax({..., beforeSend: rq => rq.setRequestHeader('USER_ROLE', document.USER_ROLE), ...});` (where `document.USER_ROLE` is correctly set elsewhere). However when inspecting `request.META` in the dispatch method of the `ScheduleView`, the `USER_ROLE` key is not present. Any help?

Comment: HTTP_USER_ROLE would be the key in META

Comment: It appears to be missing as well. The request for sure has it, checked it with Firefox dev tools.

Comment: Set the header as X-User-Role in your js. Look it up as HTTP_X_USER_ROLE

Comment: Thank you, that... eerily worked. Must be some default Django security feature stripping custom headers.

Comment: Underscores in headers. No-go.

Comment: Look at the Vary headers of your request. Also use the correct header name (which is "X-User-Role") because it's actually setting this header.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was that the js sending the header was cached but as soon as I updated it all is fine. I read that the `X-` notation is no longer recommended since 2012.